# How to traverse through a path and get the name of the files in a directory?

Tags: c#, xml

Here's something I'm not able to get the code for. I have an xml something like below:

```
<Root> 
    <MainFolder Name="Main Folder">
        <Folder Name="Folder1">
            <File Name="File1" />
        </Folder>
        <Folder Name="Folder2">
            <File Name="File2" />
        </Folder>
    </MainFolder>
</Root>
```

Now, from the code that I have, I know the location of File1. Now, here's what I want to achieve:

1. Go 2 levels back from the location of File1, i.e. Main Folder.
2. From there display each folder and File present within that folder to user.

Guys, I'm new to C#. And I seriously have no idea on how to proceed with it. Any help would be really useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with xml if I understood correctly. You want to know how to navigate through a path and display the name of the files inside a directory

Comment: LINQ to XML is your friend here. I suggest you read a good LINQ to XML tutorial, do what you can with it, and then update your question with what you've tried so far, and what went wrong (if anything).

Comment: Not totally sure what's being asked here, but if it is relating to navigating a directory path, have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you know the location of `File1` then show the code you're using to parse the XML and find this.  From here you'd need to find the ancestor you're looking for and iterate through the structure below.  As Jon says, LINQ to XML is your friend - if you're not already using it, look at it.

Comment: @greenfeet: author very clearly said `I have an xml something like below` and has even attached example of XML. Of course you **can** build a "path" from the hierarchy of parent nodes, but the question is **not** about parsing paths (meaning System.IO.Path ops and filesystem structures). This is about XML that contains structured information about some items, incidentally called "MainFolder", "Folder" and "File". Please read the posts more carefully before issuing edits to titles or bodies of the posts.

Comment: Nodes MainFolder, Folder and File are on the same level. They are all siblings.

Comment: Guys, if you think my xml itself is worng, please correct me. And as quetzalcoatl mentioned, I need to have xml. Now I need a code that can go 2 levels back to MainFolder. It prints name of folder, then it checks for Folder1 and Folder2 (inside mainfolder) and prints them. And then same thing with Files. Thanks!

Comment: Inside the node MainFolder nothing but text value!

Comment: Thanks for the correction quetzalcoatl. I edited the xml in question. Can someone help me out with C# code. Thanks!

Comment: @Praveen - you've said *'from the code I have, I know the location of File1'* - why don't you include this code and show where you're stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("file.xml");

// look for a File1
var file1 = root.Descendants()
    .Where(elem => elem.Attribute("Name").Value == "File1")
    .Single();

// go 2 levels back
var mainFolder = file1.Parent.Parent;

// display each folder
foreach (var folder in mainFolder.Elements())
{
    Console.WriteLine(folder.Attribute("Name").Value);

    // display each file
    foreach (var file in folder.Elements())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  " + file.Attribute("Name").Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander. Can't upvote. Don't have enough rep points. Also, thanks to quetzalcoatl for the xml correction.